# UnauthorizedAccessException when open serial port with Asp.Net core 3.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I cannot use serial port of Raspberry PI3 with Raspbian OS and asp.net core version 3.0, When I define COM ports and try to open it with this piece of code:

```
     SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 57600);
     if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
          serialPort.Open();
```

I got **UnauthorizedAccessException**, it seems I need some configuration changes.

Comment: Are you trying to open serial port via Asp.net core that is hosted by IIS?are you using windows ioT? i can't understand you well.

Comment: dear @Mr.AF, Yes, I can open serial port using IIS in windows, No I use Raspbian OS and dotnet core.